# Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce disable zoom on mobile only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, mobile, zoom-sdk

I am using the porto theme with the Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce. How can I disable the zoom functionality for woo gallery images for mobile?

Porto theme has this option but this Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce plugin overrides the theme settings.

Any code I can add in function.php to disable zoom on mobile?

I disabled the zoom in the Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce plugin, to use the porto theme zoom functionality. Also tried the yith product zoom and WP Image Zoom as they have the functionality to disable zoom in mobile but they don't work at all once I deactive the zoom in the  Variation Images Gallery for WooCommerce plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this snippet to your theme's `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_remove_product_zoom', 99 );

function custom_remove_product_zoom() {
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I tried this and deleted wp rocket and browser cache but it does not work. Zoom still there when you tap on image.